# How i can do an underline effect in my menu?

Tags: css, menu, hover, styling, underline

I'm practicing my CSS, so after few tutorials I started to create a simple website. I want to create something like this:

[image: Underline menu]

How can I achieve that effect? I was looking for an answer in the internet and I just found only solutions with fancy animations and underline effects, but I couldn't find solution similar to my problem. I only achieved something like this:

[image: My menu]

This is my code

```css
.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: #55415f 4px solid;
  color: #55415f;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.r_menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-bottom: black 3px solid;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_menu">
  <button class="button">Home page</button>
  <button class="button">Style demo</button>
  <button class="button">Full width</button>
  <button class="button">Portfolio</button>
  <button class="button">Gallery</button>
  <button class="button">Dropdown</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.Provide code of what you have tried till now, only providing images won't help out. As we are not able to extract code from the images till now ; ) .

Comment: And this problem is due to default `margin` of element(tag used for menu ). So to remove this issue use `margin: 0` on that element which contains the `border-bottom: 3px solid black` (i.e, your menu)

Answer (score 1):

There is a gap and 'movement' on hover because the border is going from none to 4px.

A straightforward way round this is to give a border all the time, it's just that you make it transparent when there isn't a hover. That way there is nothing to move on the hover, the space is already there.

Note: this snippet also makes the long border less wide just to make it a little more like the first image in the question.

```css
.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: transparent 4px solid;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: #55415f 4px solid;
  color: #55415f;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.r_menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-bottom: black 1px solid;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_menu">
  <button class="button">Home page</button>
  <button class="button">Style demo</button>
  <button class="button">Full width</button>
  <button class="button">Portfolio</button>
  <button class="button">Gallery</button>
  <button class="button">Dropdown</button>
</div>
```